conditional probability with respect to the stopped sigma algebra
Suppose that $\sigma$ is a almost surely finite stopping time with respect to some filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$, and let $X$ be a real walued random variable defined on the same probability space. I have been trying to show that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_\sigma](\omega) = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_{\sigma(\omega)})](\omega) \qquad \text{a.s.} $$
where by the latter i mean the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_t]$ at $t=\sigma(\omega)$, but I'm not sure how to do so rigorously. If the process is in discrete time (or if sigma takes only countably many values $t_i$, $i=0,\infty$) I think i can prove it by taking $ \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_\sigma](\omega) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_{t_n}](\omega)\boldsymbol{1}_{\{\sigma=t_n\}}(\omega)$ and basically using an argument like this.  I cannot generalize this argument to a $\sigma$ with a non-countable support. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach it or where to look for a reference?

Does the probability space have zero sets beside the empty set? Otherwise the conditional expectation is defined only almost surely. in this case pointwise equality on the state space  can not hold.

Sure, so let's ask if the equality hold almost surely

What would this mean for $t$ with $\mathbb{P}(\sigma(\omega) = t) = 0$?

Suppose $X$ is integrable and the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$ satisfies the "usual conditions" (meaning that it is right continuous and suitably complete). The (uniformly integrable) martingale $\Bbb E[X\mid\mathcal F_t]$ then admits a right continuous version, call it $(M_t)$. By optional stopping
$$
\Bbb E[X\mid\mathcal F_\sigma] = M_\sigma,\qquad\hbox{a.s.},
$$
for each stopping time $\sigma$. In effect, $\sigma$ is the decreasing limit of a sequence $(\sigma_n)$ of countably-valued stopping times, and the right continuity of $M_t$ and $\mathcal F_t$ carry the day.
